# Angular Service with dynamic scope or var

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I need a service that provide me a scope or dynamic var , so I move on to other controllers.

I did a test on JSBin and is not working .

https://jsbin.com/semozuceka/edit?html,js,console,output

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('control1', function($scope, shared) {
    shared.set('teste', {
        testecontroller1: "Apenas um teste"
    });
    $scope.teste = shared.get();
    $scope.teste2 = shared.get();
})

.controller('control2', function($scope, shared) {

    $scope.teste = shared.get('teste');
    shared.set('teste2', {
        testecontroller2: "Apenas um teste"
    });
    $scope.teste2 = shared.get('teste2');

})

.service('shared', function($scope) {

    $scope.data = {};

    this.set = function(key, obj) {
        $scope.data[key] = obj;

    };

    this.get = function(key) {
        return $scope.data[key];
    };

});
```

Comment: You can not inject $scope inside your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to use `$scope`, because it'll try to use the `scopeProvider`. You cannot inject it into a service. Also, the input for a service is an array (which contains a function), not just a function.

Having said that, you don't really need the scope at all, if you keep track of your variables inside your service.

```
.service('shared', [function() {
    var data = {};

    return {
        set: function(v, val) {
            data[v] = val;
        },
        get: function(v) {
            return (v)? data[v]: data;
        }
    };
}]);
```

[JSbin](https://jsbin.com/cogihi/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a factory service, since there is no need to create a custom one. Given the functionality of your controllers, I've created a simple factory, like so:

```
.factory('shared', function() {
  var shared;
  var data = {};

  shared = {
    set: setFunc,
    get: getFunc
  };

  return shared;

  function setFunc(key, input){
    data[key] = input;
  }

  function getFunc(key){
    if(key)
      return data[key];
    else return data;
  }
})
```

The only part that might need clarification is the `getFunc`. In `control1`, you want to get the `data` object without specifying any properties. However, in `control2` you do specify, which led to the conditional `if(key)`. So to sum up, this function checks whether there is a passed attribute parameter and returns the appropriate data.

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/q6f6PL?p=preview).

You can read more about the different Angular providers and the comparison between them in the official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

Enjoy!